# Figuring out when a JavaFX Stage is closed from inside a node

Tags: javafx-8

I have a SplitPane in which I have tabs that show dynamic data, so whenever I close a tab I want to make sure that all connections to the data are closed. This is done by listening to the sceneProperty of the node in the tab, when the SceneProperty changes to null the connections are closed, because the tab was closed.

The possibility to remove the tab from the SplitPane into its own window changed it all up a bit. Now, when the SceneProperty changes, a Task is scheduled to wait a second and then check if the SceneProperty on the Node is still null and then closes the connection. All this in order to avoid a closing of the connection when the tab is transfered to its own window, because during that the SceneProperty becomes null very briefly. This still works for closing the tab, but curiously it doesn't work when the node has its own window and apparently it's due to the fact that the SceneProperty on the window's rootNode is not null even after the window was closed.

And now I am wondering how that can be ... ?

This is basically all the code

```
// somewhere in the constructor
rootNode.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> subscriptionChange(newValue));

private void subscriptionChange(Scene newValue) {
    if (newValue == null) {
        scheduleUnsubscribeTask();
    }
}

private void scheduleUnsubscribeTask() {
    UnsubscribeTask unsubscribeTask = new UnsubscribeTask(this::handleUnsubscription);
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduledPool.schedule(unsubscribeTask, TTL_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void handleUnsubscription() {
    if (paneMain.getScene() == null) {
       closeConnection();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And now I am wondering how that can be ... ?

Closing a `Window` does nothing to the associated `Scene`. Also the `scene` property is independent from the scene being added to a window or not; It simply indicates, if the root of the node structure the node recides in is the root of a scene.

If you want to check, if a node is part of a shown scene, I recommend using `Bindings.selectBoolean`. Otherwise you'd need to (un)register/move 3 listeners (`Node.scene`, `Scene.window` and `Window.showing` properties).

```
private BooleanBinding showing;
```

```
showing = Bindings.selectBoolean(button.sceneProperty(), "window", "showing");
showing.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (!newValue) {
        scheduleUnsubscribeTask();
    }
});

...

private void handleUnsubscription() {
    if (!showing.get()) {
       closeConnection();
   }
}
```

However I recommend introducing some lifecycle for your scene content instead. This way you've got full control over disposing resources needed for the scene.

Comment: interesting, keeps throwing an exception, but so far it works, thanks